# Changing the basis to non standard in a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

Here is the given question:

Consider the linear transformation: $T:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ by: $T(x; y) = (x-y; -x + y)$:
Write the matrix representation of $T$ with respect to the basis ${(1; 2);(-1; 1)}$ (use the same basis for domain and co-domain).

Now in the solution they did the following:

1. Picked the transition matrix

\begin{equation*}
P= 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1  \\
2 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

2.Picked the matrix $A$ which is the matrix representation of the linear transformation with respect to the standard basis.

\begin{equation*}
A= 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1  \\
1 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

The found the matrix representation $B$ relative to the basis ${(1; 2);(-1; 1)}$ by solving $B=P^{-1}AP$

My question is the following: Why didn't we find $B$ by doing $B=PAP^{-1}$ since we are going from the standard basis to another one, the set-up is something I would do if I am going from ${(1; 2);(-1; 1)}$ to the standard basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\B}{\mathcal{B}}\newcommand{\S}{\mathcal{S}}\newcommand{\x}{\mathbf{x}}$Let $\B$ be the basis in question. *Note that $P$ is the transition matrix from $\B$ to the standard basis $\S$.* That is, $[\x]_{\S} = P[\x]_{\B}$, or equivalently, $[\x]_{\B} = P^{-1}[\x]_{\S}$ for all $\x\in \Bbb{R}^2$.

The matrix of $T$ with respect to $\B$ in domain and codomain (which you are calling $B$) is defined as satisfying $[T(\x)]_{\B} = \color{blue}{B}[\x]_{\B}$ for all $\x\in \Bbb{R}^2$. But

$$\begin{align*}[T(\x)]_{\B} &= P^{-1}[T(\x)]_{\S} \\ 
&= P^{-1}A [\x]_{\S} \quad (\text{since }[T(\x)]_{\S}  = A [\x]_{\S} \text{ by definition of }A)\\ 
&= \color{blue}{P^{-1} AP}[\x]_{\B}.\end{align*}$$

So the matrix you want is $B =P^{-1} AP$.

Comment: And if we were going from the given basis to the standard one we would apply $PAP^{-1}$ instead?

Comment: If instead you mean "what is the answer to my original question if instead $P$ were the transition matrix from $\S$ to $\B$?", then yes, the answer would be $PAP^{-1}$ (but not sure if you meant this, because you wrote "from the given basis to the standard one"). Just remember that in that case, $P$ would be different to the $P$ in your original post (in fact, it'd be the inverse of that).